# How do I traverse two identical trees and return a target value?

Tags: javascript, binary-search-tree

Can someone tell me why the console.log outputs the right answer, however, the return outputs null?

I am trying to traverse two identical trees, and then when a target value is found in a node in the original tree, I am trying to return the same node value in the cloned tree.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Original problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/find-a-corresponding-node-of-a-binary-tree-in-a-clone-of-that-tree/

**Codebase:**

```
var getTargetCopy = function(original, cloned, target) {
    if(original === null) {
        return null
    }
    
    original.left = getTargetCopy(original.left, cloned.left, target)
    original.right = getTargetCopy(original.right, cloned.right, target)
    
    if(original.val === target.val) {
        console.log(cloned.val)
        return cloned.val
    }
};
```

**Inputs:**

```
Your input:
original = [7,4,3,null,null,6,19]
cloned = [7,4,3,null,null,6,19]
target.val = 3
```

**Console.log:**

```
stdout:
3
```

**Outputs:**

```
Output:
null
```

**Desired answer:**

```
Expected:
3
```

Comment: where is the tree in the data?

Comment: @NinaScholz

This is how the binary tree node is defined:

function TreeNode(val) {
    this.val = val;
    this.left = this.right = null;
}

Comment: @NinaScholz I added the link to the leetcode problem I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

1. The function is supposed to return a node, not a value, so `return cloned.val` is wrong. It should be `return cloned`
2. With the following statements you are *mutating* the original tree:

   ```
   original.left = getTargetCopy(original.left, cloned.left, target)
   original.right = getTargetCopy(original.right, cloned.right, target)
   ```

   That should not happen.
3. with `if(original.val === target.val)` your code could have a false positive when `target.val` is not a unique value. Instead you should compare the node *reference*.
4. When you have a match, you should not have to recurse deeper, so perform this test *before* doing the recursive calls.
5. When a recursive call returns a node, you should immediately return *that* node and not do any other recursive call.

Here is your code corrected:

```
var getTargetCopy = function(original, cloned, target) {
    if(original === null) {
        return null
    }
    
    if(original === target) {
        return cloned;
    }

    return getTargetCopy(original.left, cloned.left, target)
            || getTargetCopy(original.right, cloned.right, target)
    
};
```

Making it a bit more condensed, it can be:

```
var getTargetCopy = (original, cloned, target) =>
    !original || original === target 
        ? cloned
        : getTargetCopy(original.left, cloned.left, target)
          || getTargetCopy(original.right, cloned.right, target);
```

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth answer! I was afraid I was not going to get any explanations since someone downvoted this post. Can you help me understand when I console log cloned, why do I get an array and not an int?

Comment: You don't get an array, but an object (displayed with braces). The int is available in a property of `cloned`: `cloned.val`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what this code block is doing? "return getTargetCopy(original.left, cloned.left, target)
            || getTargetCopy(original.right, cloned.right, target)" Is it traversing the tree? Thank you again.